# Can I use HDMI with the Intel card of my optimus laptop?

Tags: 11.10, intel, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I have an Dell Inspiron 7110 that has a Sandy bridge i7 and a discrete graphics card (GeForce 525M) from Nvidia. I want to be able to use my 23' display at home throungh hdmi but Intel integrated graphics card does not work with hdmi (VGA is not an option).

I have tried bumblebee but it does not work.

How could I use the hdmi port for my monitor. Using only the nvidia card with some driver is what I tought i could do but i don't want to give up composing because I use gnome-shell.

Any options for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI support in Linux for Nvidia Cards is not supported yet.

I have the same Nvidia Card. Using bumblebee will just allow to activate the Nvidia card and use applications with its GPU instead of the integrated card (if available).

```
optirun someapplication
```

Bumblebee project & ironhide team is working on the HDMI issue. stay tuned.
If everything goes ssmoothly, the issue should be resolved by the release of Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Although everybody says it ain't working it is! I've googled and came across this topic and this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1zkKan91i8

This is the same laptop as I have and it is working. Just connect the HMDI and open your screen settings. I have an Asus N53SV which has a GT540M in it and I am running on 11.10 with GNOME 3 (which is gnome-shell if I think) and Bumblebee working. So I'm guessing if you get Bumblebee up and running it should work.

Although the HDMI works with my TV, Sony Bravia 40" (Ubuntu says 72" (I WISH!)) it does not work with an older Philips 221T. Strange enough but HMDI does work with the Philips Brilliance 220CW, which is connect with a converter from HDMI to DVI.

Comment: What version of Bumblebee do you use? Have you done some specific configuration for this to work?

Comment: latest from the ppa of bumblebee, not ironhide. I haven't done any specific things to get it to work. By the way to get sound on your HDMI device, change the sound profile in the tab hardware (from your sound settings of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, I've tried to get HDMI-output working with my `NVIDIA GT540M` some time ago, and was not able to get it to work. I've read through a lot of forum posts, but I wasn't able to get a picture on my TV.

Now, after giving up and and coming to the conclusion that all the trouble is not worth it and deciding that I would just use Windows for watching my movies with xbmc, today after reading this post I tried again.

Just connected my HDMI-cable and it magically works, without changing anything in my configuration (as far is a know). I can even start xbmc, drag it TV-screen and watch movies - even the sound on my TV via HDMI is working!

I'm sorry that I am not able to provide any information why it is working now, just want to let you know that it is possible.